# (Python) How to get diagonal(A*B) without having to perform A*B?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Let's say we have two matrices `A` and `B` and let matrix `C` be `A*B` (matrix multiplication not element-wise). We wish to get only the diagonal entries of `C`, which can be done via `np.diagonal(C)`. However, this causes unnecessary time overhead, because we are multiplying A with B even though we only need the the multiplications of each row in `A` with the column of `B` that has the same 'id', that is row 1 of `A` with column 1 of `B`, row 2 of `A` with column 2 of `B` and so on: the multiplications that form the diagonal of `C`. Is there a way to efficiently achieve that using Numpy? I want to avoid using loops to control which row is multiplied with which column, instead, I wish for a built-in numpy method that does this kind of operation to optimize performance.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Just a note for anybody looking at this: `A*B` in NumPy is element-wise multiplication, not matrix multiplication (which is `a.dot(b)`).

Comment: are `A` and `B` of type `ndarray` or `matrix`?

Comment: @Blair, that's the case if `A` and `B` are `numpy.array`. If they are `numpy.matrix`, you can use `A*B`

Comment: @gnibbler D'oh. I'm conditioned to the point of forgetting `numpy.matrix` exists because I habitually work with three dimensional data. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Bitwise, `A` and `B` are matrices, sorry for not clarifying that

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I might use `einsum` here:

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 10, (3,3))
>>> b = np.random.randint(0, 10, (3,3))
>>> a
array([[9, 2, 8],
       [5, 4, 0],
       [8, 0, 6]])
>>> b
array([[5, 5, 0],
       [3, 5, 5],
       [9, 4, 3]])
>>> a.dot(b)
array([[123,  87,  34],
       [ 37,  45,  20],
       [ 94,  64,  18]])
>>> np.diagonal(a.dot(b))
array([123,  45,  18])
>>> np.einsum('ij,ji->i', a,b)
array([123,  45,  18])
```

For larger arrays, it'll be much faster than doing the multiplication directly:

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 10, (1000,1000))
>>> b = np.random.randint(0, 10, (1000,1000))
>>> %timeit np.diagonal(a.dot(b))
1 loops, best of 3: 7.04 s per loop
>>> %timeit np.einsum('ij,ji->i', a, b)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.49 ms per loop
```

[Note: originally I'd done the elementwise version, `ii,ii->i`, instead of matrix multiplication.  The same `einsum` tricks work.]

Answer (score -1):

```
def diag(A,B):
    diags = []
    for x in range(len(A)):
        diags.append(A[x][x] * B[x][x])
    return diags
```

I believe the above code is that you're looking for.

Comment: That's not how [matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Matrix_product_.28two_matrices.29) works

Comment: Sorry.  Didn't know if you meant scalar product or matrix product.