# Cleanest way to compute less in a function by implicitly knowing what the callback / caller function is in Python?

Tags: python, continuations

The specific use case I have in mind is that say I have two matrices like

```
A = [[1, 1], [1, 1]]
B = [[2, 2], [2, 2]]
```

and I want to write a function like `multiply` to compute their dot product like this:

```
def multiply(X, Y):
    # some code to compute the ij-th entry of the resultant matrix
    return result
```

however immediately after this computation say that I am applying a trace operation (sum of the diagonal entries). Then obviously I could not care less about the entries in the resultant matrix that are not diagonal. So my question is, what is the cleanest way in Python to tell `multiply` that the only operation on what will be returned by it will be an operation that only needs small parts of the result (so as to only compute that result). The first thing I think of is something like

```
def multiply(X, Y, only_diag=False):
    if only_diag:
        # only return i, j entries
    else:
        # return all entries

result = trace(multiply(A, B, only_diag=True))
```

However I'm interested to know if there is a way to implement `multiply` such that it recognizes the function `trace` as being the caller function, and so implicity it knows that `only_diag=True`.

Thanks :)

Comment: Doing that implicitly is inherently "unclean".  To do it cleanly, make it explicit.

Comment: Is it though? The reason I feel it would be good is that if any developer at any point writes `trace(multiply(A, B))` and just forgets to explicitly state that `only_diag=True` then that is wasted time. If, in every single case of `trace(multiply(...))` we only care about diagonal entries, wouldn't it be cleaner just to make it an implementation detail?

I look at it kind of like: if I'm telling Google to search the word 'good restaurants' then it optimizes to find restaurants near me first with good ratings. I don't need to say 'good restauraunts, near me, rating > 4'

Comment: There are a number of reasons why those kinds of optimizations are fraught with peril in a dynamic language like Python.  One major reason is that you can redefine what `trace` refers to at runtime.  So how do you know that `trace` is what you think it is?  You as a human know that because you know what the trace means, but the program seeing a function named `trace` can't magically know that it only needs the diagonal.  If someone named their trace function something else (like `matrix_trace`) then your optimization would fail.

Comment: If you want to do numerical calculations, check out [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/). Interestingly, while numpy has both the `dot` (multiply) and `trace` function, it does not have combination of both.

Comment: Aside: if you're going to use `numpy` to compute the trace of the product, you might be interested in the `einsum` approach I used [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437817/python-how-to-get-diagonalab-without-having-to-perform-ab/17437885#17437885).

Comment: By doing this, you are introducing a hidden/implicit variable into your (so far) pure function. Really not worth it. Magic tricks are cool in shows, not in programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a clean way to know which function is called afterwards as in your example.

In the code `trace(multiply(A, B))`, the *multiply()* function is **called before** *trace()* rather than being **called by** *trace()*.

In CPython, if you want to know the **caller function**, then the [*sys._getframe()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys._getframe) function
can help:

```
import sys
from inspect import getframeinfo

def multiply(X, Y):
    print getframeinfo(sys._getframe(1))

def trace(Z):
    pass

def multiply_then_trace(X, Y):
    Z = multiply(X, Y)
    return trace(Z)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = [[1, 1], [1, 1]]
    B = [[2, 2], [2, 2]]
    multiply_then_trace(A, B)
```

This prints:

```
Traceback(filename='/Users/raymond/Documents/tmp3.py',
          lineno=11,
          function='multiply_then_trace',
          code_context=['    Z = multiply(X, Y)\n'],
          index=0)
```

To achieve your goal of faster code execution, the easiest thing to do is just write a `trace_multiply(X, Y)` function that has custom optimized code and invoke it explicitly rather than trying to cobble together automatic detection.

Another alternative is to use lazy evaluation of the matrix multiplication.  That way, you can skip the parts of the multiply that you don't need later.

Hope this helps :-)