# Using numpy to contract indices with delta function

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have two NxM arrays in numpy, `a` and `b`. I would like to perform a vectorized operation that does the following:

```
c = np.zeros(N)
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(M):
        c[i] += a[i, j]*b[i, j]
```

Stated in a more mathematical way, I have two matrices A and B, and want to compute the diagonal of the matrix A*B (being imprecise with matrix transposition, etc). I've been trying to accomplish something like this with the `tensordot` function, but haven't had much success. This is an operation that is going to be performed many times, so I would like for it to be efficient (i.e., without literally calculating the matrix AB and just taking the diagonal from that).

Comment: duplicate?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437817/python-how-to-get-diagonalab-without-having-to-perform-ab

Comment: `c = np.einsum('ij,ji->i', a,b)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's correct. Wasn't able to find the answer you linked when I looked, but you're right that this is a duplicate.